# Fetch API - cross domain

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

[Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) , "successor" of AJAX seems promising, but I can't seem to find any example of cross-domain (or cross-origin if you will), and in fact, there's not much about this online except same-origin example, so does this mean JSONP is still the de-facto, straight-forward way to go in upcoming years? CORS just seems unrealistic in terms of configuration annoyance.

Comment: "CORS just seems unrealistic in terms of configuration annoyance" — CORS is trivial to implement for simple requests. It only gets complicated if you want to do POST requests with uncommon body encoding formats or custom request headers … both of which are utterly impossible with JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spec you linked to:

> To allow sharing resources cross-origin and allow for more versatile HTTP requests than possible with HTML's form element, the platform has a CORS protocol layered on top of HTTP.

So cross-origin with fetch is handled in exactly the same way as it is handled with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: yeah but it doesn't explain how does the **COPS** integrates with the *Fetch API*, and they provide no examples, and the links on that document points to nowhere except the section they are already at. So, you say COPS is independent from *Fetch* and what they are actually saying is don't use *Fetch* for cross-origin.

Comment: It integrates with the fetch API in exactly the same way as it integrates with the XMLHttpRequest API. Transparently. If you make a fetch request and the URL is on a different origin, then the browser follows the CORS spec.

Comment: That comment was better than the answer itself :) thanks.